# "Важно" — в начале фразы

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор, сложное-предложение

> Важно: защитники «Тоттенхэма» располагаются достаточно узко, шансов разрезать их передачей между не так уж много.

***Важно*** — это неполное предложение в составе сложного предложения? Что это за синтаксическая конструкция?

Comment: Пример неудачный. Располагаться  узко(?!), передача между(?!).

Comment: Нормальный футбольный сленг, да и к "важно" отношения не имеет.

Comment: @Niemand К "важно" отношения не имеет, это правда. Но "передачай между"  — нормальный футбольный сленг? Хотелось бы увидеть хоть один пример.

Comment: Так они главным образом устные, примеры-то. Я немного неправ – скорее, не сленг, а просто сокращение.

Comment: @М_Г "Располагаются узко" вполне употребимо и совершенно не режет слух. Примеров в книгах находится достаточно много, особенно в научной и спортивной лексике. Второе намного хуже, конечно.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, что, не мудрствуя лукаво, стоит признать это *важно* самостоятельной предикативной основой (в составе сложного предложения), ср.: *Важно, что защитники...*, как представляется, ничем иным, как частью сложного предложения *важно* здесь быть не может.